# both if and else condition are executed and both returns a result

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have 2 data on my watcher field, first one has availability child and the second one doesn't have..

```
router.get('/getNewWatcher/:sdate/:shft/:type', function (req, res) {
    reqDate = req.params.sdate;
    reqShift = req.params.shft;
    reqType = req.params.type;

    var watcher = database.ref('watchers');

    watcher.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        var promises = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve({
                    childKey: childSnapshot.key,
                    childData: childSnapshot.val()

                });
            }));
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then(function (snapshot) {
            var dataSet =[];

            snapshot.forEach(function (result) {
                if (result.childData.availability) {                            
                    dataSet.push({
                        child: result
                    })
                }else {
                    dataSet.push({
                        child: 'No Available Watchers'
                    })
                }
            });
            res.json(dataSet);
        })
    });
});
```

My code works.. when I run this script to check if a watcher has availability child it will return a watcher which has the availability child.. but for some reason `else` conditions also return `'No Available Watchers'` so my problem is when I run this script both my `if` and `else` condition return a result which isn't quite what I'm looking for and I cant figure it out why.

Comment: well, clearly both the if and the else block can't be executed in the *same iteration of `snapshot.forEach`* - so it must be happening in different iterations ... so `dataSet` must have more than one item in it, correct?

Comment: yeah without using the if condition it has 2 or more item on my dataSet. but one doesn't have availability child while the other one have

Comment: no, with the if condition you'll get as many items in the array as without ... because in both cases you push something to the array ... but that doesn't mean bot true and false condition are being run on each iteration

Comment: ohh isee.. so i tried making putting if condition outside my foreach to check `if dataSet.length > 0` it will return the result with availability child else no watcher.. and it works.. but i dont know if it is the right approach or is there any better way to handle this.

Comment: right approach? depends on your expected input, and what each input should produce as output - you don't have enough information in the question to say

Answer (score 0):

[Here is my Firebase architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Ntt.png)

I used same thing in Swift, here is its code maybe it's useful to understand.

```
    databaseRef.child("users").child(key).child("following").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            self.lblFollowing.text = String(following.count)

        } else {

            self.lblFollowing.text = "00"

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment chain with Jaromanda X I have the impression that you want to return a list of available watchers, **or** a single "No Available Watchers" when there are no watchers available anywhere.

To do this you have to move the "no watchers at all" detection outside of the loop:

```
var dataSet =[];

snapshot.forEach(function (result) {
    if (result.childData.availability) {                            
        dataSet.push({
            child: result
        })
    }
});

if (dataSet.length === 0) {
    dataSet.push({
        child: 'No Available Watchers'
    })
}

res.json(dataSet);
```